# How well does Rebol scale in an FCGI setup?

Tags: fastcgi, rebol, rebol3, rebol2

I plan to write a fairly decent sized web application in Rebol (CGI on Apache 2 at the moment) but the initial performance tests have been very discouraging. I get a measly 4-5 requests/sec when I run apache benchmark on the application. I'd like to know if others have had similar issues and if FastCGI really helped them.

And afaik, Rebol only supports FastCGI in the Command and SDK versions, has or will this change anytime soon since R3 has been opensourced?

Comment: It has come up in the [chat room for Rebol and Red](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) (please join if you can) that we need a mod_rebol, but also your scenario sounds suspiciously odd in terms of performance, let's debug it in chat.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while since I've used the FastCGI facilities in Rebol, so I can't really answer the first question very well, but I can help on your second question, though you might not like it.

Noone has recreated the `fastcgi://` scheme for R3 yet. I say "recreated" because R3 has a completely different port model than R2, so port schemes aren't at all portable between the two platforms. And this is in addition to the R2/Command port scheme being built-in native code, which also wouldn't be portable to R3 even if it were open sourced because R3's system model is different too. And regardless of its portability, R2 contains a lot of commercially licensed code that Rebol Technologies doesn't have the right to open source - pretty much everything that it could open made it into R3 already. So if it isn't there already, it's safe to assume that it's not at all compatible or not openable.

It would be faster and easier to start over from scratch in R3 with a brand new `fastcgi://` scheme that follows the R3 model. The most that the R2 source would help with, even if we had it, would be to document the FastCGI protocol, and AFAIK the protocol is better-documented elsewhere. It would likely be a good idea in that case to make a host port that is optimized for this kind of thing, something which is a bit easier to do in R3.

On the plus side, from what I remember the FastCGI protocol is not that difficult to do, and the new R3 port model is a lot better for this kind of thing, so starting from scratch might not be too difficult. And if we're lucky, this can all be done in user code that just runs on the regular R3 interpreter, no host code adaptation necessary. So the news doesn't have to be that bad.

*Now an attempt to answer your first question*: It depends.

It really depends on what you are trying to do, and how you have things set up. CGI has the overhead of starting the process every time, so it's only fast if the process startup overhead is significantly less then the rest of the overhead of the request (filesystem or database access, for instance). Rebol, particularly R2, has a significant amount of process startup overhead because it is an interpreter that has some built-in interpreted code to load when it starts up. You can minimize that startup overhead by using the SDK to create your app with only the code you need, but that still might not help enough in your particular case (not knowing what you're trying to do).

FastCGI is a way to get rid of that process starting overhead by running an out-of-process app server instead of starting a new process per request. For something like Rebol which has significant process startup overhead, the savings can be just as significant.

One thing that you need to consider is that R2 has a single-thread-per-process model for the most part, so if you want to handle multiple concurrent requests you either have to do them in parts in the same process (like Node.js) or have FastCGI allocate multiple server processes to handle multiple requests independently, or maybe both. Be sure to ask the Rebol experts for advice if the prospect of this is intimidating, or just set up FastCGI to start up more app servers to run at the same time.

So, how many requests you can do per second with a FastCGI setup depends on how you configure FastCGI, how you write your FastCGI handler code, and how much and what kind of work your requests are doing.

It is telling though that you are getting 4-5 requests per second in CGI mode. That's unusually slow. Rebol's startup overhead isn't anywhere near that slow in the worst case. That means that either your requests are doing *a lot*, or that you don't have enough RAM to be running more than a couple CGI processes at a time, or that you have CGI configured badly. I'm not sure that FastCGI can help as much in that case as just using better hardware or doing a better job of configuring Apache. Nonetheless, make sure you have enough FastCGI worker processes and write your handler to handle multiple requests at the same time and you'll save as much overhead as you can.

Good luck!

Comment: Darn it! I was really hoping to go full speed writing the application in Rebol. Looks like I'll have to choose another platform now. My script's not heavy at the moment, no dependencies or database calls, however, I do have a very large, deeply (6-7 levels) nested blocks that I parse for each request but I've noticed that this doesn't seem to affect the performance at all, which tells me that you have it spot on. It's the executable startup time that's the downer.

Comment: Also 4-5 requests is what I get on the Debian box. Interestingly, I have a similar script (the original, running as a cgi script) in Ruby doing much much more and I get ~30 rps on the same box. It beats me! 

But what's even more interesting is that I get around ~30 rps (both Rebol and Ruby versions) on a Windows box running Apache! Go figure!

Comment: Now, I don't know how difficult it is to write an Apache module, but I'm seriously considering writing a mod for Rebol since I can't seem to let go of the idea. But really, I'm afraid I'll be sucked into it full time and won't have time for the real project at hand! Ha! I guess, we'll see.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Check the other answers. There is no reason built into Rebol itself why you should be getting 4-5 requests per second. 10 times that fast is more common, comparable to Ruby (which has similar startup overhead); 100 times that fast in some cases depending on hardware and configuration. Deeply nested blocks are easy to parse, so it's not that.

Answer (score 4):

Its hard to answer any performance issues when we have no idea what script you are trying to run.  :-)   some of the questions which follow, might seem dumb, but I really don't know much about the context in which you are trying out Rebol CGI.

4-5 request/second is not normal for a CGI app running under Apache.  I can assure you that with any kind of H/W which is even a decade old, you should be getting MUCH more than that.

what kind of tests are you doing?   For me, rebol starts up so quickly, that it can open, show its console and quit in between refreshes (at 60Hz), so I don't even see it appear.

maybe some little part of your code (or a library you use) has a delay or a small wait (perharps some network delay to a DB server).

also, have you tested the outgoing network speed of the server?

you can also try out cheyenne, which is a Web server built with Rebol, which is able to serve several hundred requests a second, when the scripts themselves, obviously, don't take too much time.

In Fact, cheyenne and apache should be able to saturate the network speed of your server relatively easily... if you have lengthy scripts, and need more throughput just add more workers to have more parallel tasks (as long as memory use is within acceptable limits)

Comment: I'll give Cheyenne a try. Sadly, I'm afraid I can't share the script here but rest assured it's not trying to do anything out of the ordinary. Please see my comments to Brian's post above. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm curious, just what platform are you using? Could your issue be solely based on how it is installed there?  also, which version of rebol are you using. view? core?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu on a VirtualBox. It's got plenty of processor and memory on it. I thought I was low on resources too but given the same script Ruby seems to outperform Rebol which is quite surprising. I'm using R2 Core.

Comment: very strange.  you mention that cheyenne is also slow... I am starting to think that you may have a problem with your installation.  I am wondering if there is a slowdown on rebol boot.  do you have anything in a user.r or a visible delay when you start within a shell?   it should be "instantaneous".

Comment: Running stock Debian/Ubuntu/Cheyenne. Don't know if running in a virtual box might be causing these aberrations? I'll try running the same setup straight on my linux laptop and let you guys know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you can get ~30 rps on the same box using Ruby and same performance between Ruby and Rebol on a Windows box, most probably, something is wrong with your Rebol CGI and/or configuration.

Try running your Rebol CGI script from command-line in a loop to see if the cause of the slowness is the script or your Apache config.

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways:

- Let apache play proxy to a real rebol-webserver, like cheyenne. More complex to keep it running on startup etc.
- Run rebol behind another language thru a pipe. Use a language which has fastcgi.
- Run rebol as tcp-daemon, let a fastcgi-language contact it.

Comment: Thanks dt2. I've tried Cheyenne but I'm afraid it out of the question as it's quite slow too. I didn't know about about options 2 and 3. Could you please care to elaborate for me?

Comment: http://shairosenfeld.blogspot.de/2011/01/parent-and-child-pipe-ipc-in-ruby.html

Instead of exec "/bin/sh" you run a rebol-script. Feed the cgi-request from ruby to rebol, wait for answer, feed next request. You need a madeup protocol to seperate the requests, pass their size or something.